# Style elements to take the whole line but be only as wide as the content

Tags: css

I have a simple list:

```
<ul>
  <li>Element 1</li>
  <li>Element 2</li>
  <li>Element 3</li>
</ul>
```

How do I make each `<li>` element displayed on it's own line, but at the same time being only as wide as it's content, so that when I set a background or border on them, it will be only as wide as the content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Flexbox and set:

1. `flex-direction: column` so each `li` appears on separate line
2. `align-items: flex-start` because default value is `stretch` and that will make each `li` take full width of parent element and you want each `li` to have width equal to width of content.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
li {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Element 1 some more text</li>
  <li>Element 2 text</li>
  <li>Element 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Great clean solution. I didn't know that setting `align-items: start;` would change how the width of those elements gets calculated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `float` and `clear` on them:

```css
li {
float: left;
clear: left;
background: #fb4;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Element 1</li>
  <li>Element 2</li>
  <li>Element 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Right, this would work as well, but the Flexbox solution is simply more elegant.

Comment: yes, but on the other hand nobody sees the elegant code. Keep in mind: Old browsers will fail when using flexbox, but can handle float and clear.

Comment: I myself and my coworkers see the elegant code! : D But really, in a big project, if not here, one would use Flexbox in many places elsewhere, as many layouts aren't possible to achieve without it. So in the end one usually wouldn't be able to get rid of using Flexbox and get the extra support of very old browsers.